# How to calculate camera view angle (per Fragment in Fragment-Shader) (WebGL / OpenGL)

Tags: math, opengl-es, webgl, raytracing, raycasting

i've given all three matrices (Model, View, Projection) in Fragment Shader. Now i like to calculate the view angle per fragment. camera has a perspective of e.g. 45°. how can i do it? with this i like to simulate a viewing ray origin from the camera. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You need to calculate the inverse of `Projection · View · Model` and supply this as a further uniform to the shader (fixed function compatibility does provide a `gl_ModelViewProjectionMatrixInverse`). Use this to unproject the point (0,0,0,1) and (0,0,-1,1). The result are two points in model space forming a ray.

Comment: Is it right, that your ray origins at the center of the world and pointing towards the end in view-direction? Is this ray orthogonal to view-plane? What I actually need is a ray origin from camera, not from view-plane. So, I guess I need the inverse of model-view matrix instead of model-view-projection-matrix? And: What's actually the 4th point coordinate? My Code so far: `mvpMatrix = mat4.multiply(pMatrix, mat4.multiply(vMatrix, mMatrix));
mvpMatrixInv = mat4.inverse(mvpMatrix);
gl.uniformMatrix4fv(shaderProgram.viewDir, false, mvpMatrixInv);`

Comment: Ah, forgot to say: I need the ray pointing to the current fragment in fragment shader.

Answer (score 0):

You need the projection matrix (Here I'll call "proj"):

```
tangent_x = 1/proj[0][0];
tangent_y = 1/proj[1][1];

angle_x = arctan(tangent_x);
angle_y = arctan(tangent_y);
```